# How to solve error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at the time of installing netbeans8 in debian

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, debian

I am trying to install netbeans 8 in debian-7.0-amd64-minimal. (VPS)

1st I have installed java/JDK latest version (1.8.0_20) by following 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps

Next I am trying to install netbeans by following

http://installnetbeansdebian.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-install-netbeans-73-ide-complete.html

when I run

```
./netbeans-8.0-php-linux.sh
```

it displays the following error.

```
Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Extracting installation data...
Running the installer wizard...

Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

Anybody knows, how to fix this?

Comment: YOu should probably post the contents of your .sh script if you want help

Comment: ah, I have simply downloaded that from netbeans website. http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.0/final/bundles/netbeans-8.0-php-linux.sh

Answer (score 9):

Had a similar issue, for some reason the command

```
$ sudo chmod -x netbeans-8.2-javaee-linux.sh
```

didn't create executable file out of the script, so I had to use GUI method, as it shown here in the second answer:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-run-from-termina

then as the user **Firestorm** suggested just dropped *sudo* and it worked for me:

```
$./netbeans-8.2-javaee-linux.sh
```

Installed perfectly even created "Development" department in the "Application" menu and nested program start tag there. Debian-8 x64 KDE

Comment: chmod -x removes execute permission

Answer (score 6):

Just had the same issue here (Fedora 25, Netbeans 8.2). It only occurs, when executing the installer as root which seems to be a problem with a root-privileged gui in a non-root-privileged environment.

Solution: Either install netbeans as normal user in your home directory OR launch the installer as root with the switch '--silent':

```
./netbeans-8.2-html-linux-x64.sh --silent
```

which will install netbeans in /usr/local.

Comment: Works for NetBeans 12.2 under CentOS 8

Answer (score 2):

Maybe late. For ubuntu 17

```
azuka$ : xhost +
azuka$ : sudo su
root$ : sh netbeans-8.2-php-linux.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on "Fedora 26". But I resolved it by repeating the same procedure but not as 'root' or 'sudo'. I.e:

Change directory to locate the downloaded file.
then.

```
$ chmod +x netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
$ ./netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is nearly exactly two years old, but still actually occurred here just now.

I had this too on a Slackware system. I was trying to install it like you (because Slackware doesn't provide NetBeans packages) and I was typing in a virtual terminal window after executing su. The problem was the exact same as yours: I got the NoClassDefFound exception and the installer stopped. The solution was to execute the NetBeans installer as a normal user, or as the same user that you're logged in as in the X session. Java errors can be a bit cryptical, but the solution's as easy as that.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply close netbean if you open it already
1.install openjdk
2. download netbean 
and where you download it use below command
$./netbeans-8.2-javaee-linux.sh

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to execute the NetBeans installer as a normal user, or as the same user that you're logged in as in the X session

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to execute the NetBeans installer as a normal user, or any user other than root.
define JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME as environment variable

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while installing Oracle Developer Studio via ssh X forwarding. I switched jdk from SE to 1.7.0 openjdk (update-alternatives --config java) and then managed to install. I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I use:

```
sudo bash -x Apache-NetBeans-12.1-bin-linux-x64.sh --silent
```

and with this I coud install netbeans, but the version 12.1.

Answer (score -1):

It is much easier (and more reliable and more secure) to use package management system to install software. All you need to do is to use the following command to install *netbeans* on [Debian](http://debian.org):

```
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```

Although *netbeans* version 7 will be installed (ver. 8 is not available from native Debian repository yet) you won't be struggling to make it work.

Besides please be careful with instructions to install java/JDK -- the method they describe is not the best. If OpenJDK is not sufficient for you then you might be doing something wrong. If you absolutely have to try Oracle's Java (unfortunately there are some corner cases when it might be needed) please use [java-package](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/java-package) to build your own Java package (.deb) from downloadable Java binary.

Comment: i have got the following warning - /usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../platform/lib/nbexec: WARNING: environment variable DISPLAY is not set

Comment: @Onlyjob: I'm having the same problem on CentOS, which does not include netbeans in their repository.

Comment: @Tahmina: The NetBeans install script needs an X-Windows display, which it finds by reading the DISPLAY environment variable.